# Por que a minha função está concatenando ao invés de somar os números?

Tags: javascript, string, tipagem

Estou aprendendo JavaScript e estou quebrando a cabeça com este código que criei. Por que a minha função está concatenando ao invés de somar os números que armazeno nas variáveis?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Aula 05 Java Script</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var num1,num2;

        num1 = prompt("Digite um número ","");
        num2 = prompt("Digite outro número para somar ","");

        function soma(){
            var res;
            res=num1+num2;
            alert("Reultado da Operação "+ res);
        }

        soma();

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque o retorno da função [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) é sempre uma `string`. Então a adição fará a concatenação de ambas. Se deseja somar os números precisa converter a variável para um tipo numérico, isto se dá com [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), por exemplo.

```js
num1 = prompt("Digite um número ","");
num2 = prompt("Digite outro número para somar ","");

function soma(){
    var res = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
    alert("Reultado da Operação "+ res);
}

soma();
```

Ou se preferir que as variáveis já sejam numéricas:

```js
num1 = parseInt(prompt("Digite um número ",""));
num2 = parseInt(prompt("Digite outro número para somar ",""));

function soma(){
    var res = num1 + num2;
    alert("Reultado da Operação "+ res);
}

soma();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/SumNumbersInputed.js).

Também é possível usar o [`ParseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) se deseja que o número permita números com parte decimal.

Note que se a conversão não for possível, afinal a pessoa pode digitar um texto, pode não dar o resultado esperado já que o valor provavelmente será 0, ou algo que ele consiga converter, mas não ser bem o que foi digitado.

Comment: Respondemos no mesmo minuto :) `+1`

Comment: Muito obrigado!
   Agora além de resolver compreendi o motivo!

Grande abraço.

Answer (score 9):

O problema é que o retorno do `prompt` é uma string ([dá uma olhada aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/sbwaj6v8/)).

Assim, se converteres essas strings em números o teu código já vai funcionar.

Por exemplo, usando o `Number`:

```
var res = Number(num1) + Number(num2);
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2d1otn4a/

---

## Nota:

- maneiras diferentes para converter strings em Numeros

Em JavaScript há o [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) que converte uma string num numero inteiro, removendo a parte decimal sem arredondar. Podes também usar o [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), ou [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). Todos convertem strings em numeros.