# Alterar o tipo de uma variável em uma declaração de uma linha, altera o tipo das variáveis que vem e sequência, porquê?

Tags: javascript

Ao fazer a declaração de mais de uma variável do mesmo tipo em uma linha, eu consigo posteriormente fazer operações aritméticas com esses valores. Ex.:

```js
let num1 = 10, num2 = 5, num3= 10;

let resultado = num1 + num2 + num3;

console.log(resultado); //O resultado será 25
```

Porém, se eu alterar o tipo da primeira variável `num1` para string e tentar realizar a mesma operação:

```js
let num1 = "10", num2 = 5, num3 = 10;

let resultado = num1 + num2 + num3;

console.log(resultado); //O resultado será 10510
```

Por que esse comportamento ocorre? Por que todas as variáveis são convertidas?

Comment: Primeira observação: Quando uma variável string inicia,isso acontece,agora se for depois não e alguns caso dar NaN.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126163/por-que-a-minha-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-concatenando-ao-inv%C3%A9s-de-somar-os-n%C3%BAmeros

Comment: Eu posso te dar exemplo: `"2"+2="22"; 2+2+"2"="42"`

Comment: Acho que vale ressaltar que o fato das variáveis estarem declaradas na mesma linha não faz diferença nenhuma, o que importa é somente o tipo delas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso acontece porque ao encontrar um valor texto, todo o restante é tratado como texto porque o sinal de operação `+` se transforma na operação de concatenar.

Mas repare que isso só ocorre ao encontrar um texto, veja esse exemplos que as operações antes são realizadas, e as posteriores (ao texto) são todas tratadas como texto:

```js
console.log(10+20+30+40);  // tudo somado
console.log(10+20+30+"40"); // 10+20+30 somado, depois concatenado
console.log(10+20+"30"+40); // 10+20 somado, depois concatenado
console.log(10+"20"+30+40); // tudo concatenado
console.log("10"+20+30+40); // tudo concatenado
```

Answer (score 4):

Complementando a [resposta do Ricardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401254/112052), o fato das variáveis estarem declaradas na mesma linha não faz diferença nenhuma. Se estiver assim, dá o mesmo resultado:

```js
let num1 = "10";
let num2 = 5;
let num3 = 10;

let resultado = num1 + num2 + num3;

console.log(resultado); // 10510
```

Pois o que define se o `+` será tratado como "soma" ou "concatenação" é o [tipo das variáveis envolvidas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40848608) na operação.

Se quiser forçar que `num1` seja um número, basta usar [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```js
let num1 = "10";
let num2 = 5;
let num3 = 10;

let resultado = parseInt(num1) + num2 + num3;

console.log(resultado); // 25
```

Comment: boa, e gostei desse link dos "tipos de variáveis" bons exemplos

Comment: @RicardoPontual JavaScript tem umas bizarrices, né? O que acontece se somar `[] + {}`? É o mesmo que `{} + []`? Respostas: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: é verdade, acho que por não ser tá bem tipada, a linguagem permite essas coisas bizarras, dai os bugs mais sinistros aparecem :)