# Repetindo ao inves de somar

Tags: javascript

Por que esta repetindo o numero ao invés de somar?

```js
var valor = prompt("calculo")
var valor1 = prompt("adição")

if (valor + 0 || valor1 + 0) {
  document.write(valor += valor1)
} else {
  document.write("valor incorreto")
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Todo retorno do prompt é uma string, nesse caso você está somando 2 string, onde ocorrerá a concatenação.

Você pode usar o parseInt() para corrigir o problema.

```js
var valor = parseInt(prompt("calculo"))
var valor1 = parseInt(prompt("adição"))

if (valor + 0 || valor1 + 0) {
  document.write(valor += valor1)
} else {
  document.write("valor incorreto")
}
```

Comment: Não há necessidade de responder uma pergunta que é duplicada, conforme [mencionei em meu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/524865/repetindo-ao-inves-de-somar#comment952971_524865). Se acha que pode fazer uma resposta que agregue valor para a comunidade, faça-a na [pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126163/100416). Entretanto, sua resposta não difere das existentes.